# Are all context-sensitive languages decidable?

Tags: formal-grammars, turing-machines, undecidability, context-sensitive

I was going through the [Wikipedia definition of *context-sensitive language*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_language) and I found this:

> Each category of languages is a proper subset of the category directly above it. Any automaton and any grammar in each category has an equivalent automaton or grammar in the category directly above it.

I could see that linear-bounded automaton is directly below decider in the article's ordering. If this is the case, then that means every computation on a LBA will halt at some point (since every LBA would be a decider). But I feel that there may be some computation which can run on a LBA at the same time never to halt. For example we can write a computation on LBA which would

1. read the first symbol on the tape and move right;
2. read the next symbol and move back left.

This (useless) computation (which is obviously a LB computation) would run indefinitely oscillating left and right and never halt and hence cannot be a decider. Where am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Deciding a CSL is independent of whether there are non-terminating LBA: there only *has to exist* an LBA for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, all context-sensitive languages are decidable, since they can be accepted by a LBA (as you said), and a Turing machine is more powerful than a LBA.

However, you were asking about something else. Can there be LBA that cycles? The answer is yes. You gave an example. However, you can modify every LBA $M$ to a Turing machine $M'$ that accepts the same language but never cycles. To see this, observe, that you can simulate $M$ on $M'$ and keep track of all configurations the LBA has attained so far. If there is one configuration that shows up twice, you detected a cycle. In this case you stop rejecting. The important thing here is that the LBA uses on linear space, and hence the number of its configurations is bounded.

Comment: If anyone still did not understand this answer, I suggest you refer to Slide 3-4 of [this presentation](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~elomaa/teach/iTCS-12-7.pdf) for additional explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at this book:
[Introduction to Languages and the Theory of Computation by John E Martin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0072322004)

page 283: **There are still open
questions concerning context-sensitive languages, such as whether or not every
CSL can be accepted by a deterministic LBA.**

Comment: How does this answer the question? Context-sensitive languages are all decidable, irrespective of whether you need deterministic or nondeterministic linear space.